# laravel Form Request = if button was clicked

Tags: php, laravel

I need to know which button was clicked inside a request form on laravel since i have Save and Update buttons.

```
App\Http\Requests\RegistrationRequest.php

public function rules()
{
    $myrule = [ 'name' => 'required', 'age' => 'required' ];

    if (isset($_POST['save']))
    {
        $myrule['application_form'] = 'required';
    }
    elseif (isset($_POST['update']))
    {
        $myrule['application_form'] = 'required_without:is_application_form';
    }

    return $myrule;
}
```

i need to know if the button that was click is Save or Update because I'm requiring for the application_form file field to be required if the Save button is clicked but I only require the application_form field if the is_application_form hidden field is empty.

the setup above is working for name and age field but ignores the codes inside the IF conditions.

Comment: Add `;` in the end of lines.

Comment: updated with ; thank you.

Comment: Don't use `$_POST` in laravel, you have the `request()` helper which is more reliable since your request may be altered by middleware while the post isn't.

Comment: i have tried $request->has('save'), $this->has('save'), and nothing worked, please help what im missing.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a solution. I'm saying you should do it anyway. Post your form as well.

Comment: can i ask what form? my blade or my controller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In html

```
<button type="submit" name = "submit" value = "Save"></button>
<button type="submit" name = "submit" value = "Update"></button>
```

In code

```
if($request->submit == "Save")
{
......
}
else if($request->submit == "Update")
{
.....
}
```

Comment: tested and worked! thank you so much, i also found some working code that also solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way if user clicks this button validation for php, laravel.
If you are validating in laravel you can use this in controller.

```
if (isset($_POST['save']))
{
    ....
}
else
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

addition to Rajob's answer, the code below also works:

```
switch($this->method())
      {
        case 'GET':
        case 'DELETE':
        case 'POST':
        {

        }
        case 'PUT':
        case 'PATCH':
        {

        }
        default:break;
      }
```